# Will returning a vector<vector <int> > from a function invoke any move constructors in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In C++11 will returning a `vector<vector<int> >` from a function invoke any move constructors? Or would the below code just make another copy of the all the vectors and their elements?

```
vector< vector<int> > Func() {
  vector< vector<int> > vec;
  //vec is filled here
  return vec;
}
```

For stl containers of simple types is there a general to find when a move constructor is used or copy is made when returning them as values from functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` statements are specifically covered by the standard to be automatically treated as a move. So yes, this will invoke the move constructor.

The letter of the law for this is C++11, `[class.copy]§31+32`:

> **31** When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object ... This elision of copy/move operations, called *copy elision,* is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cvunqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function's return value
> - ...
>
> **32** When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, **overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.** If overload resolution fails, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue.
> ...

(Emphasis mine)

Combined and applied to your case, this means that when returning a local variable from a function, a move is attempted first and only if that's not possible, a copy will be performed.

(And, as @BjornPollex points out, it's quite likely even the move will be elided)

Comment: In the particular code shown by the OP, NRVO could optimize away any copies or moves.

Comment: The function itself will elide the move. Whether it can be elided in the caller depends on whether it's first initialization of the receiving variable or not.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Most likely. But (N)RVO is always optional, whereas trying the move first is *required* by the standard.